# Polymorphism in Object construction

Tags: perl, oop, polymorphism

I want to create specific Object according to the type argument.
Pseudo code looks like this.

```
sub new {
    my $type = shift;
        if($type eq "S1") {$interface = X->new(); }
        if($type eq "S2") {$interface = Y->new(); }
etc...
    return $interface;  
}
```

Options might be:

> 1. Substitute "package" name with $type argument. Requires package name coordination with $type.
> 2. Use Hash{S1 => X} in the Master constructor to select Value according to $type passed. Requires Hash maintenance when adding new
>      Object types.

I don't like any of above. Looking trully polimorphic way to accomplish that.
Thank You,
k

Comment: use factory design pattern: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: I don't understand what sort of solution you expect. It seems to me that there has to be a way of relating `S1` to `X` and `S2` to `Y`, so something like your option 2 is unavoidable. Is there something about `S1` and `S2` that you haven't told us?

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would likely be to use a factory pattern. A factory method takes the parameters for creating an instance of your class, then decides which object to instantiate and return from that. This can also make dependency injection easier for testing.

You'd probably be looking at something like this (in Java-esque code), with an employee object:

```
public class EmployeeFactory 
{

    public static create(String type)
    {
        switch (type) {
            case type1:
                return new EmployeeTypeOne();
            case type2:
                return new EmployeeTypeTwo();
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unrecognized type");
         }
    }
}
```

Your employees would inherit from a common interface or abstract class. You can use the factory to handle constructor parameters as well if you prefer, just try to keep things fairly reasonable (don't pass a million parameters - the factory should internally handle complex objects)

See http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConstructorWithFactoryMethod.html for more information.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question, which is about choosing a class based on a parameter to the constructor. You have just rewritten the OP's pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

You might like `Module::PluginFinder` for that. Create all your specific types in a specific namespace and give them each some identifying (constant? sub?) that the main dispatcher will then use to identify which class handles a given type.